# programmatically send sms in titanium appcelerator

Tags: android, sms, appcelerator, titanium-modules

I have been trying to **send sms from my app without user intervention programmatically** however there is no success.
I have tried the intent method

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent(
{
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SENDTO, data: 'smsto:1234567890'
});

intent.putExtra('sms_body', 'Geolocation:'
            + ' long ' + e.coords.longitude 
            + ' lat ' + e.coords.latitude);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);        

});
```

This sends the sms as well as the message text properly. but the only problem is it need human intervention. it calls the inbuild sms functionality and we have to press the send sms button I want to automate the process.

I found this link on github [Click Here](https://github.com/omorandi/TiAndroidSMS)

It says we can automate the process. When I try to install the module titanium shows the module installed correctly, however in the ti app editor it says ti.android.sms module not supported by titanium SDK version 3.1.2 GA . 
In the build.properties file which the original developer has provided it shows his paths to sdk 3.0.0 GA. I tried to change the build.properties file and provided the paths for android, titanium and google api with the versions and then install the module but I have no success.

Comment: i found the solution myself the problem was i was not installing the proper module zip file. we need to install the zip file found in the DIST folder . the proper way of installing a module can be found [link]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-6zZ-435q0 here [/link] i'm quite new to titanium and stackoverflow . hope this will be helpful for other developers in app sms is a real problem in Titanium